# MIcrosoft Word: Accidentally clicked 'Don't check for this issue"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, spell-check

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I made a mistake using the Word 365 grammar and spelling checker and I need a quick answer. I recently upgraded to Office 365 (my school offers it for free), and I've noticed that in addition to the traditional red squiggly lines for misspellings and unrecognized words, the proofing checker now underlines language that could be made more clear or concise with a grey-brown squiggly line. This may just be a replacement of the green line from previous versions, as I haven't seen anything underlined green in this version, but I suppose that isn't very relevant. On to the issue itself:

Sometimes these "clear and concise language" suggestions are helpful, and other times I choose to ignore them. One such time when I chose to ignore the suggestion was when it underlined "in an effort to" and suggested I replace it with "to." However, when I right-clicked on the suggestion, I accidentally clicked "don't check for this issue" instead of "ignore once." (I'm paraphrasing the option I clicked, I haven't been able to reproduce the menu). I went into the proofing tab under file/options, but I didn't find any unchecked boxes that matched what I was looking for. Does anyone know how to undo this and make Word check for clear and concise language again?

Answer (score 4):

Under File Options, in Proofing tab, scroll down to “When correcting spelling and grammar in Word” section, click the “Recheck Document” button then “Yes”, it will reset the options in this document.